# how to create relationship in code first in asp.net core

Tags: .net-core, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

```
Failed executing DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [AspNetUsers] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUsers_Citys_City_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([City_ID]) REFERENCES [Citys] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The `ALTER TABLE` statement conflicted with the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint `FK_AspNetUsers_Citys_City_ID`. The conflict occurred in database `UserDBtest3", table "dbo.Citys", column 'ID'`.

**class City**

```
public class City
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int State_ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("State_ID")]
        public virtual State State { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

        public City()
        {
            ApplicationUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        }
    }
```

**class user**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(150)")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public int UserRoleID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserRoleID")]
        public virtual UserRoleTest UserRoleTest { get; set; }

        public int Person_ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Person_ID")]
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

        public int City_ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("City_ID")]
        public virtual City City { get; set; }

        public int State_ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("State_ID")]
        public virtual State State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Data context**

```
public class AuthenticationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
    {
        public AuthenticationContext(DbContextOptions<AuthenticationContext> option):base(option)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<UserRoleTest> UserRoleTests { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Person> Prsons { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

        public DbSet<City> Citys { get; set; }

        public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Entity Framework [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

If you want relationships to be discovered by convention, can follow the pattern: `<principal entity name><primary key property name>`

```
public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    //...omitted for brevity
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // omitted for brevity

    public City City { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you prefer dont use the convention, you can use the `[ForeignKey]` annotation:

```
public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //...omitted for brevity
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // omitted for brevity

    [ForeignKey("IdCity")]
    public City City { get; set; }
    public int IdCity { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you prefer not to have a foreign key property (not recommended).

> If no foreign key property is found, a shadow foreign key property will be introduced.

```
public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    //...omitted for brevity
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // omitted for brevity

    public City City { get; set; }
}
```